# pySpark Timestamp as String to DateTime

Tags: pyspark

I read from a CSV where column time contains a timestamp with miliseconds '1414250523582'
When I use TimestampType in schema it returnns NULL.
The only way it ready my data is to use StringType.

Now I need this value to be a Datetime for forther processing.
First I god rid of the to long timestamp with this:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("date", col("time")[0:10].cast(IntegerType()))
```

a schema checks says its a integer now.
now i try to make it a datetime with

```
df3 = df2.withColumn("date", datetime.fromtimestamp(col("time")))
```

it returns

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type Column)
```

when I google people always just use col("x") to read and transform data, so what do I make wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema checks are a bit tricky; the data in that column may be `pyspark.sql.types.IntegerType`, but that is not equivalent to Python's `int` type. The `col` function returns a `pyspark.sql.column.Column` object, which often do not play nicely with vanilla Python functions like `datetime.fromtimestamp`. This explains the TypeError. Even though the "date" data in the actual rows is an integer, `col` doesn't allow you to access it as an integer to feed into a python function quite so simply. To apply arbitrary Python code to that integer value, you can [compile a udf](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html) pretty easily, but in this case, pyspark.sql.functions already has a solution for your unix timestamp. Try this: `df3 = df2.withColumn("date", from_unixtime(col("time")))`, and you should see a nice date in 2014 for your example.

Small note: This "date" column will be of `StringType`.

Comment: It works if I cut the timestamp to seconds: `df2 = df.withColumn("date", from_unixtime(col("time")[0:10]))`